# .minecraft folder doesn't have the correct files

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a .minecraft folder but when I open it, I don't see the files that should be there.

I only have the following folders in it:

- assets
- crash
- report
- libraries
- logs
- server
- resource-packs
- versions
- launcher_profiles
- .json

How do I get the normal .minecraft folder?

Comment: What are you missing?

Comment: All missing files and folders are created when they become needed - or if you need them, make them by hand.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're missing the "Saves" folder. Try creating a Minecraft world to create the folder.